# Why doesn't this shell code work?

Tags: vba

I'm working in VBA. Right now, I'm in UserForm3. There is a text box that displays a user-defined path.

What I need to do next is actually get the file to open. I was trying to use a shell but it isn't working. Anyone know why?

```
Private Sub Open_Button_Click()

Dim myPath As String
myPath = FileName.Text    'Gets the string, FileName, from module 1
Dim shell As Object
Set shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
shell.Open myPath

End Sub
```

The alternative version, and the one I'd prefer to use, is this:

```
Private Sub Open_Button_Click()

Dim shell As Object
Set shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
shell.Open FileName

End Sub
```

Maybe I'm just tired, but I'm not seeing why it isn't working. I've been toying with it for awhile.

I'm using Autodesk Inventor 2011...running it through VBA Editor

Thanks ahead of time,
Alyssa

JPEG:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkHfF.jpg

EDIT 1, What Has Been Tried So Far:

(from help in comments)

-setting it to modeless from modal (nothing happens)

-double-clicking the file to make sure it opens (it does)

-putting file in separate module and running (nothing happens)

Comment: What happens? error message? What type of file? Double checked `Filename` has a value?

Comment: Nothing happens at all. It doesn't do anything. No error, no anything. Yes, filename has a value.

Comment: What type of file is it?

Comment: One person said something about identifying Autodesk Inventor in Systems->Advanced->Environment Variables->Path....is that necessary? I tested the shell to just open Autodesk Inventor and it worked just fine.

Comment: So double clicking works? Is Filename the full path? Is your form modal - try it non-modal?

Comment: Double-clicking doesn't do anything....Filename is the full path (as shown in the JPEG above). Is there a specific way to make it non-modal? I just took off the "vbmodal" code. Sorry, I've only been using VB for about a week.

Comment: Well if you double click the file in explorer and nothing happens its not related to VBA

Comment: Oh! In explorer? Yes, the file opens from explorer. I thought you meant from my code.

Comment: I also looked up how to switch between modal and non-modal. That also did not work.

Comment: If you put the code in a normal module sub and run it does it work?

Comment: It "runs" with no errors, but absolutely nothing happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it!

```
Private Sub Open_Button_Click()

Dim myPath As String
myPath = FileName.Text    'Gets the string, FileName, from module 1
Dim Shell As Object
Set Shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Shell.Open (myPath)

End Sub
```

I just enclosed "myPath" in the Shell.Open function.

Comment: Can't think what that would happen at all!